# Plotting Dirichlet Series $L_{\tau}(s)$ related to Ramanujan tau function in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, wolfram-alpha, dirichlet-series

According to wikipedia, Ramanujan tau function $\tau:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is defined by equating the coefficients of the power series on both sides of the identity:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tau(n)q^n=q\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^n)\tag{1}$$

The associated Dirichlet series is defined as:

$$L_{\tau}(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\tau(n)}{n^s},\text{Re}(s)>13/2\tag{2}$$

$L_{\tau}(s)$ can be defined for other $s$ by method of analytic continuation.

Question:
Is $L_{\tau}(s)$ implemented, like Riemann $\zeta(s)$ function, in a software like Mathematica(or Wolfram alpha) so that it can be readily plotted against complex variable $s$?

Thanks-
mike

EDIT: I found the solution at the suggestion of @Mark McClure. It is called "RamanujanTauL".

Comment: I guess there's [DirichletL](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletL.html). I'm not positive that it's exactly what you're looking for.  It is possibly more general so you might need to fiddle with it to find the proper incantation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After I looked at the Documentation for "DirichletL", I found the entry I was looking for. It is called "RamanujanTauL". The definition is identical to equation (2) above.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: MathWorld [has an article on the Ramanujan $\tau$ Dirichlet series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TauDirichletSeries.html).